# Шесть или шестеро?

Tags: числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание, собирательные-числительные

Спор возник. Как правильно будет звучать предложение:
"Трясусь над **шестерыми** своими детьми" или "Трясусь над **шестью** своими детьми". Формулировка именно такая, встретила предложение в первом варианте на просторах Интернета.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!! Очень помогли!

Answer (score 6):

Возможны оба варианта.

Собирательное числительное определяет  количество лиц КАК СОВОКУПНОСТЬ, но в такой ситуации в этом нет необходимости (понятно, что речь идет о детях одной семьи, кроме того, используется местоимение "своими"). **Поэтому вариант  "трясусь над шестью своими детьми" более приемлем и более характерен для современного языка.**

Также следует отметить, что в состав собирательных числительных входит девять слов: двое, трое, четверо, пятеро, шестеро, семеро, восьмеро, девятеро, десятеро, причем три последних слова практически в речи не применяются. Таким образом, некоторые числительные имеют определенную (привычную) частотность применения или сочетания.

Примеры

Жениться бы ему на ней, а он, вместо того, с шестерыми ребятами ее бросил! (М.Е. Салтыков-Щедрин).

Осталась ни вдова, ни мужня жена Аграфена Ивановна Мутовкина с шестерыми детьми, мал мала меньше… (П. И. Мельников-Печерский).

А другая была судьба у мужика с шестью детьми (А. И. Солженицын).